# Is there a way to have Canvas update everytime data is entered into Entry fields?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I have this code where it draws the plan view of each building. It works perfectly, but I don't want to always click the "Draw" button to see it. I've done OptionMenu where if menu 1 changes, the items in menu 2 change. I've also done Labels where it prints the sum of the Entry fields. They both use trace but I can't seem to find anything about that using the Canvas. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("drawing lines")
root.state('zoomed')
# Building 1
L1 = Label(root, text="Building 1 Width")
L2 = Label(root, text="Bay 1 Spacing")
L3 = Label(root, text="Bay 2 Spacing")
L4 = Label(root, text="Bay 3 Spacing")
L5 = Label(root, text="Bay 4 Spacing")
L6 = Label(root, text="Bay 5 Spacing")
L7 = Label(root, text="Bay 6 Spacing")
L100 = Label(root, text="Sidewall Offset")
L1.place(y=20)
L2.place(y=50)
L3.place(y=80)
L4.place(y=110)
L5.place(y=140)
L6.place(y=170)
L7.place(y=200)
L100.place(y=230)

E1 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Building Width
E1.place(x=200, y=20)
E3 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 1 Width
E3.place(x=200, y=50)
E4 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 2 Width
E4.place(x=200, y=80)
E5 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 3 Width
E5.place(x=200, y=110)
E6 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 4 Width
E6.place(x=200, y=140)
E7 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 5 Width
E7.place(x=200, y=170)
E8 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 6 Width
E8.place(x=200, y=200)
E100 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Sidewall Offset
E100.place(x=200, y=230)


# Building 2
L8 = Label(root, text="Building 2 Width")
L9 = Label(root, text="Bay 1 Spacing")
L10 = Label(root, text="Bay 2 Spacing")
L11 = Label(root, text="Bay 3 Spacing")
L12 = Label(root, text="Bay 4 Spacing")
L13 = Label(root, text="Bay 5 Spacing")
L14 = Label(root, text="Bay 6 Spacing")
L8.place(x=400, y=20)
L9.place(x=400, y=50)
L10.place(x=400, y=80)
L11.place(x=400, y=110)
L12.place(x=400, y=140)
L13.place(x=400, y=170)
L14.place(x=400, y=200)

E9 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Building Width
E9.place(x=600, y=20)
E11 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 1 Width
E11.place(x=600, y=50)
E12 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 2 Width
E12.place(x=600, y=80)
E13 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 3 Width
E13.place(x=600, y=110)
E14 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 4 Width
E14.place(x=600, y=140)
E15 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 5 Width
E15.place(x=600, y=170)
E16 = Entry(root, width=5)  # Bay 6 Width
E16.place(x=600, y=200)


sf=3  # Scale Factor

def draw():
    total1=0
    of1=20 # Horizontal Offset
    of2=20+int(E100.get())  # Vertical Offset for building 1
    w = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=500, bg='white')
    w.place(y=250)

    list1=[]
    list1.append(E3.get())
    list1.append(E4.get())
    list1.append(E5.get())
    list1.append(E6.get())
    list1.append(E7.get())
    list1.append(E8.get())
    list1 = [0 if x =="" else x for x in list1]
# Building 1
    for i in range(0, len(list1)):
        total1 = total1+float(list1[i])
        w.create_rectangle(sf*of1, sf*of2, sf*(of1+float(total1)), sf*(of2+float(E1.get())))

# Building 2
    total2=0
    of3=total1
    of4=20  # Vertical offset for building 2
    list2=[]
    list2.append(E11.get())
    list2.append(E12.get())
    list2.append(E13.get())
    list2.append(E14.get())
    list2.append(E15.get())
    list2.append(E16.get())
    list2 = [0 if x =="" else x for x in list2]
    for i in range(0, len(list2)):
        total2 = total2+float(list2[i])
        w.create_rectangle(sf*(total1+of1), sf*of4, sf*(of1+ (total1+float(total2))), sf*(of4+float(E9.get())))

    #Building 1 Center Line
    w.create_line(sf*of1, sf*(of2+(float(E1.get())/2)), sf*(of1+total1), sf*(of2+(float(E1.get())/2)), dash =(5,5))
    #Building 2 Center Line
    w.create_line(sf*(of1+of3), sf*(of4+(float(E9.get())/2)), sf*(of1+total1+total2), sf*(of4+(float(E9.get())/2)), dash=(5,5))
    #Building 1 Bay spacing Markers
    total3 = 0
    for i in range(0, len(list1)):
        if list1[i] !=0:
            total3 = total3 + float(list1[i])
            w.create_text(sf*(of1+total3 - float(list1[i])/2), sf*(10+float(E100.get())), text=list1[i])
        else:
            break

    # Building 2 Bay Spacings
    total4 = 0
    for i in range(0, len(list2)):
        if list2[i] != 0:  
            total4 = total4 + float(list2[i])
            w.create_text(sf*(total1+of1+(total4 - float(list2[i])/2)), sf*10, text=list2[i])
        else:
            break

    #Building 1 Width Marker
    w.create_text(sf*10, sf*(of2+float(E1.get())/2), text= E1.get())
    #Building 2 Width Marker
    w.create_text(sf*(of1+total1+total2+10), sf*(of4+float(E9.get())/2), text = E9.get())




b = Button(root, text="Draw", command = draw)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about updating a canvas when you enter data in an Entry widget, we don't need much more than the canvas and one or two entry widgets plus enough code to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the return key to the entry, to call the draw function:

```
entry.bind('<Return>', draw)
```

Here is a small example that draws the number of points entered in the `Entry`, at random locations on the canvas on the `Canvas`

```
import random
import tkinter as tk


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 600

def draw(dummy_e):
    n = int(entry.get())
    dx, dy = 2, 2
    for _ in range(n):
        x, y = random.randrange(WIDTH), random.randrange(WIDTH)
        canvas.create_oval(x+dx, y+dy, x-dx, y-dy)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='cyan')
    canvas.pack()

    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.pack()

    entry.bind('<Return>', draw)

    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I needed. The only thing I changed was <Return> to <FocusIn> and it works. I didn't realize that the event had that in there. I thought it was going to be a little harder to code than that.